# Can Jira's allowable-component list come from Confluence?

Tags: confluence, integration, jira

Can Jira source a list of allowable-components from a set of articles (labeled things) in Confluence?

I am thinking that Jira Components, such as when they are restricted to a fixed list, represent agreed-upon items in the product chain.  Confluence seems like a good place for such components to be specified, discussed, or otherwise *elaborated upon*.

I would really like my KB to drive the work in Jira, and give docs/context to that work.  Can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this out of the box. You could write a full-fledged Java plugin to do it, or you could likely use the [Script Runner for JIRA plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner) to do most of the work.

You could also use an external script or application that talks to the APIs for Confluence and JIRA.

Comment: I haven't used Script Runner yet.  If you have, can you post something that demos how to integrate with the Components admin for a project?  Don't worry about where the list comes from; the intro to how to get script runner to do this would, itself, be a a leap that I could build from.

Comment: @NewAlexandria It's not something I've done before. You basically have access to all or most of the live java objects you would if you wrote a full plugin, plus all kinds of shortcuts built-in to script runner. The docs plus some web searches will probably get you where you need though. [Here's an example of someone setting components](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/92882/set-component-in-groovy-script).

Comment: That seems to [lead to understanding PicoContainers](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/ComponentManager.html).  Is that correct?  The Pico container URL in that previous link is broken.  Do you think I'm looking at the right docs?

Comment: @NewAlexandria I guess that's correct, though to be honest I've never heard the term PicoContainer before. My background is that I've done some programming, lots of scripting, but very little Java and I've never written a full JIRA plugin. Given that, I found using Groovy with ScriptRunner to be an altogether decent experience by fiddling with it. ScriptRunner has several areas that let you paste and run code within its web administration. If you've got any basic coding experience, you'll pick it up; a trial is probably worth your time as long as you're willing to to build this whole solution.

Comment: I can code it, I'd just like a more directed answer to how "Jira's allowable-component list [can] come from Confluence" — for the purposes of leaving a good Q&A history on this site.

Comment: @NewAlexandria I understand; I think it's a bit outside the scope of this SE site, and even on SO it would probably be too broad, as I (or a potential answerer) would basically have to write it from the ground up to demonstrate it. Since you have access to JIRA internals with ScriptRunner or a plugin, you can manipulate the component list. Confluence has a REST API, which could be accessed by the same code. That's the high level overview. Maybe someone else could give you a more detailed walkthrough, but I'm afraid for me, it would take quite a bit of time to show anything more detailed.